# Exclude rows not participating in an optional relationship

Tags: nhibernate

I have a DB schema as

```
Episode(id INTEGER)

Study(id INTEGER, id_episode INTEGER (NOT NULL), FOREIGN KEY (id_episode) REFERENCES Episode(id))
```

Episode table used to have a relationship toward Study and had in code a Criteria query like

```
sess.CreateCriteria<Episode>.
    […]  # multiple filtering criteria added here 
    .Add(Expression.IsNull("Study"))
```

Now that the `Episode.Study` column is gone, how do I request only rows from Episode that are *not* in relationship with a Study row?

By reading the documentation and the web I have the impression I have to do an outer join onto Study and then filter there, not sure if that is the case or how to express that in the Criteria API.

I am using `5.x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var criteriaResult = session.CreateCriteria<Episode>("episode")
    // more filter
    .Add(Subqueries.NotExists(DetachedCriteria.For<Study>().Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Episode.Id", "episode.Id")).SetProjection(Projections.Id)))
    .List();
```

or

```
var linqResult = session.Query<Episode>()
    // more filter
    .Where(e => !session.Query<Study>().Where(s => s.Episode == e).Any())
    .ToList();
```